# CakePHP console is telling me my table cannot be found

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP version 2.0.6 and I keep getting odd behavior when using the console to bake my project.

My database config file is set up fine and works when I access it through a browser, however baking a view causes the error `Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table of view not found: 1146 'jahans_wimbrick.products' doesn't exist` even though I know it does exist. Does anyone know what could cause this or how I could fix it?

I'm already getting odd behavior from my console: I'm unable to use `./cake bake` to bake a project, instead I'm having to use `./cake bake -app "/file/path/.../app"` just avoid the console telling me my databse.php isn't present, even though it is and I configured it manually myself. Maybe these two problems are related?

Thanks.

Edit: I am able to create everything manually and got through the CakePHP tutorials fine just doing that, problems only seem to arise when using the console.

Comment: What happens if you cd to your app/Console directory and then run cake bake without any parameters

Comment: I get the same problem - it doesn't recognise the databse config file and asks me to set up a new one in the console.

Comment: Are you using windows? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html See the part which starts: If you are on Windows Vista or 7, you should follow the steps below.